# What are the primary business challenges for Firefly Aerospace to capturing a large enough market share of the 1-ton payload market to be successful?

Tags: cost, business, smallsat, smallsat-launcher, firefly-aerospace

The recent CNBC video *How Ex-SpaceX Engineers Are Fueling The Space Race With Firefly* (linked below) is worth a watch, and notes include the following:

> a team comprised of industry veterans, Firefly Aerospace wants to be a dominant launch provider in the growing small satellite market.

The video says that their two stage *expendable* carbon fiber rocket will put a 1000 kg payload into LEO, with plans to extend that capability to 1,500 kg.

In the screen shot below a graphic lists this together with three competitors for mass to LEO (defined there as 160 to 1000 km).

**Question:** What are the primary business challenges for Firefly Aerospace to capturing a large enough market share of the one-ton payload market to be successful?

These numbers suggest abl Space Systems is very competitive on paper, but a lot can change in the next few years. Is there a big one-ton payload market out there; what would factors prevent a simple, cheap, throw-away one-ton launcher company from being able to capture this market and hold on to it?

| Provider | up to (kg) | cost (\$million) | ratio (\$million/100 kg) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Firefly Aerospace | 1,000 | 15 | 1.5 |
| Rocket Lab | 300 | 7 | 2.3 |
| ASTRA | 100 | 2.5 | 2.5 |
| abl Space Systems | 1,350 | 12 | 0.9 |
| SpaceX F9 (for context) | 22,800 | 62 | 0.3 |

related:

- [What fire will Firefly fly, and when? (update/clarification on planned launch vehicle)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25579/12102)

[image: screenshot from the CNBC video How Ex-SpaceX Engineers Are Fueling The Space Race With Firefly] click for larger

Comment: You left Relativity Space out of your list. Their Terran 1 launch vehicle is definitely a competitor in that range, and they expect to launch in early 2022.

Comment: It's not just ex-SpaceX engineers who work at Firefly. I know several of them, and they did not come from SpaceX. In addition, there are many ex-SpaceX engineers who have moved to other startups. The promise of having to work a mere 50 to 60 hours per week is very appealing to ex-SpaceX engineers, where working "only" 60 hours per week means you're a complete slacker.

Comment: @DavidHammen Oh it's not my list! I just reproduced the list that's in the screen shot as text so that the question does not rely on images. I'm try to be careful about that. Thanks for the addition, I think folks will pick that up from your comment.